# How can I get the name of a python class?

Tags: python, reflection, inspection

When I have an object foo, I can get it's class object via

```
str(foo.__class__)
```

What I would need however is only the name of the class ("Foo" for example), the above would give me something along the lines of

```
"<class 'my.package.Foo'>"
```

I know I can get it quite easily with a regexp, but I would like to know if there's a more "clean" way.

Comment: Use the dir() function with your favourite objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
__class__.__name__
```

Answer (score 3):

foo.__class__.__name__ should give you result you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
Python 3.0.1 (r301:69561, Feb 13 2009, 20:04:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class foo:
...     x = 1
...
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.__class__.__name__
'foo'
>>>
```